# AngularJS - Change API by SSL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, ssl

```
var serviceROOT = 'http://myapisite.com/api/account/';
```

But I want, when I user come to site with `https` my api change to `'https://myapisite.com/api/account/'`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the scheme with javascript like this:

```
var scheme = window.location.protocol; //http: or https:

var serviceROOT = scheme + '//myapisite.com/api/account/';
```